# opencart wishlist access

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to figure out how administration can have access to each customer's wishlist items, perhaps adding a tab to the Sales/Customer/ area where General, Transaction, Rewards Points that would be for wishlist. Really would be handy, as we work with several organizations that have "secret gifters" that always want to send something wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a current feature of OC, and I've not seen anything that does it, but your on the right tracks for an ideal spot for it to go